# Do a full non-ajax post from a partial view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, partial-views

This more of an out of interest question than an urgently need an answer one, but I have been trying to find a good example of how to deal with a full postback from a partial view in asp.net MVC. The obvious example is the case where you have a small login form on every page. You can easily accomplish this through an asynchronous post back using jquery, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it without the use of javascript. I know it may be pedantic, but I don't like the idea of assuming the client has javascript enabled, particularly in this day and age where responsive design/ progressive enhacements are the big buzzwords around, so having you log in tied to javascript means that anyone on a simple mobile device won't be able to use it since their device probably won't support it.

Anyone have any ideas / examples of how to accomplish this? It's such a simple thing to implement in web forms I can't believe it's as tricky as I've heard it made out to be in MVC.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Being a partial view doesn't make any difference. Just have a form that posts back to the server.

Comment: The problem I've had with doing that in the past is that I get null reference errors on the controller for the current page (view), since the model data for that controller doesn't exist in the posted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a form within the view, that's all. The form will POST to its controller action method and generate a full page refresh (if that's what you mean by a full postback - I guess it is) irrespective of whether its a partial or not.

You can have multiple forms on a MVC view, and each one of them will give you a full page refresh, whereas with WebForms the pattern was one main form per page.